# How can I vertically center this css/javascript based modal dialog?

Tags: css

I've successfully centered horizontally my overlay dialog with margin: 0 auto;.

But I have no idea how to center it vertically.

Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
/* =Overlay
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#overlay {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
}

#overlay #dish-popup {
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: #fff;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;
     width: 810px !important;
     height: 700px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the rule 100% for every parent in your html structure for this to work, if all parents do not have a height of 100% then it would not center vertically on any screen.

Comment: when you mean all parents you mean to all the elements before that div?

Comment: All the elements that have opening tags before the element and are closed after the div, in other words the elements that 'wrap' your div. Including body and html, they should have height adding too. Do something like, height: 100%, min-height: 100%, height: auto; // height auto ensures it works in older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lots of methods to achieve CSS vertical centering depending on your layouts(divs or tables). I would suggest you look here

[CSS VERTICALLY CENTERING](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out vertical offset with jQuery and set it when page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var top = ($("body").height() / 2) - ($("#dish-popup").height()/2);
   var left = ($("body").width() / 2) - ($("#dish-popup").width()/2);
   $("#dish-popup").offset({top: top, left: left});
});
```